# Adding many custom markers and many custom info windows in Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am really just looking for the best way to accomplish this. I've seen the code how to do these individually, but is there a away to do it for say, 100 points? Or do i need to set the custom image and custom info for every point I create?

Also, is there a backend, say SQLite, that i could incorporate the help accomplish more efficiently?

The app I'm building could have 1000's of points, and I REALLY wouldn't want to code everyone of those...but i would!

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check this one: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Google Fusion Tables - they support 100,000 points per layer and 5 layers, for 500,000 points altogether. You access them via an SQL-type language that runs on Google's servers - exactly where your data will be when you upload it and that makes them very fast.

The infowindows are programmable too.

You load your CSV into a Fusion Table (like an Excel spreadsheet) in your Google drive and get a key to that table and you then use the key in your Javascript.

I created the following website with Fusion Tables and I don't have a clue about Javascript! See Skyscan website [here](http://www.skyscan.co.uk/mapsearch). I won't mind if you click `View Page Source` :-) By the way, if you click on `Modern Collections` on that page, you are actually turning on/off 25,000 markers and it is almost instantaneous. There is also `Marker Clustering` available which lets you de-clutter maps with massive numbers of markers and automagically replace them with a single "fatter" marker.

There is a good tutorial [here](http://simonrogers.net/2013/01/27/how-to-make-a-map-with-google-fusion-tables/).